# Direct POST into URL not working?

Tags: html, api, url, post, error-handling

I am trying to contact an API by posting the parameters in the URL. I am unsure whether it will respond in XML or JSON, but it is one of the two, however, it says there is an error.

This is an example of what I'm submitting. I am receiving this in response:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I do not know what is going on... I followed the syntax of the POST I believe, my only remaining question about the syntax would be whether the ? is in the right spot. The page API does work when I POST using PHP...

Or maybe it is working, the browser just isn't capable of understanding an XML or JSON response? (I'm using chrome so I do not think this is the issue)

Otherwise, if anyone has any insight on this, I'd be greatful

A different browser yields this error:

```
 XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: 
Line Number 1, Column 1:Array
 ^
```

Comment: hit that URL in the browser. and see what it returns. or use firebug, fiddler. a tool that you can see the request and response.

Comment: well the error tells you what the problem is. you are not returning any document. u usually get this error, when you return XML, with json you usually get back  `{} `

Comment: @DarthVader So you're saying it is actually returning something? the browser just can't interpret it (XML)?

Comment: @DarthVader and I used firebug just now. Not that adept at it, but under the XHR tab, it says 0 requests. So does that mean it did not go through?

Comment: why would a browser wouldnt understand XML? they have been understanding XML for a very long time. why dont you use firebug, charles or fiddler and see the raw response. seriously.

Comment: dont look at XHR, look under ALL

Comment: @DarthVader Response: array, the parameters appear to have been read well... what else can I examine for an error?

Comment: look at how u are building your xml? copy the XML response to a XML validator and see if it s valid XML

Comment: @DarthVader I did not write the API I am wishing to contact, but I know it works. Here is what is given in the XML portion of Firebug. XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: moz-nullprincipal:{b8b670af-0f65-4db3-999d-0f1226255974} Line Number 1, Column 1:

Array
^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the syntax of the URL does seem to be fine, you imply that the API expects the parameters in POST. Adding them to the actual URL means the parameters are passed in GET, rather than POST.

You could try to test this by making a little HTML form containing all the relevant parameters and passing them to this API via POST, and see if that gives you the expected result.

Comment: I see your point. But the API can accept GET requests as well. So that is not the issue. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

your issue is how their being sent to the api it should be url-encoded
http://api.example.com/api/?apikey=asdfa23462=example&ip=208.74.76.5

should be

http://api.example.com/api/?apikey=asdfa23462&=example&ip=208.74.76.5

also another issue i see is that you have ?apikey=asdfasfsdafsd&=example

the =example could well be the issue all together.

just some thoughts from what i see.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was a typo, at least from what I can tell. I fixed what you were talking about. If you still see an error please let me know!

Comment: could you let us know the api your attempting to use, that's the only way any of us are going to be able to debug successfully. From what you've given you should be having no issues, can you access that url via your browser and get any sort of response back?